# Взять собаку: ЗА поводок или НА поводок?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, предлоги

С одной стороны, человек берётся рукой **за** поводок, когда к ошейнику собаки этот поводок уже прикреплён.
С другой стороны, человек берёт собаку «**на** поводок», когда ошейник на собаке уже есть, а поводок к нему ещё не прикреплён.
Когда собака срывается с поводка, т. е. убегает вместе с поводком, то я беру её **за** поводок.
Когда собака бегает сама по себе и мы встречаем другое животное, то я беру её «**на** поводок».

Правильно ли я рассуждаю или есть более строгие/конкретные правила?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Comment: @Aer Довольно проблематично удаленному участнику это делать ;-)

Comment: @Aer вообще вопрос был перенесен отсюда https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions. Там юзер существует, а тут нет.

Comment: @Aer Этот юзер может видеть ответы?

Comment: @М_Г видеть может — но уведомления ему не приходят (скорее всего).

Comment: @Aer, А уведомление о том, что вопрос перенесен, он получил?

Comment: @М_Г я постараюсь выяснить это.

Answer (score 2):

В словарях не нашел, поэтому излагаю свое понимание:

Взять собаку *на поводок* означает прикрепить поводок, чтобы водить ее на этом поводке. Тут главное в том, что собака будет *на поводке*, то есть управляемой. А взять собаку *за поводок* – ухватиться за поводок, прикрепленный к собаке (сравните: взять человека за рукав).

Представим ситуацию, когда собака убежала вместе с поводком. Вы догоняете ее и берете *за поводок* (хватаетесь за поводок) и *на поводок* (ее свобода теперь ограничена поводком).

Собака *сорвалась с поводка* означает, что ограничивающий ее свободу поводок остался (у вас в руках или привязанный к дереву), а собака убежала. А если собака убежала вместе с поводком, то некорректно говорить, что она сорвалась с поводка.